# Is there any method that calls automatically when we click on to the textview?

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I need a help from ur side.

Actually I need to call a method automatically when I click on to the textview.
Is there any delegate methods or any other process for this.

Anyone's help will be much appreciated.

Thank you,
Monish.

Comment: Guys please give me a quick answer its very urgency for me to work on it.

Comment: It might help get answers if you specified whether you were talking about the Mac OS X NSTextView or the iPhone UITextView. Based on your other questions I'm assuming "iphone" and retagging as such.

Comment: I am Talking about UITextView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [UITextView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html) and the [UITextView Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html). Maybe textViewShouldBeginEditing: is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

UITextView inherits from UIScrollView, so maybe

(BOOL)touchesShouldBegin:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event inContentView:(UIView *)view

Overridden by subclasses to customize the default behavior when a finger touches down in displayed content.

Comment: actually I had a textview in tableview cell.In that the touches is not working.Is there any other suggestions regarding to this.